# how to change filter in active_admin if i have relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

if in my model i have relation like this :
model degree :

```
class Degree < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :states
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :states, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

model state :

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :degrees  
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :degrees, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

how to override filter for state in index degree active admin if i have relation like above?

Comment: what do you mean by "override filter for state"? What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: in active admin index page i want override relation for filter field state_id

Comment: what's currently showing, and what would you want it to show instead?

Comment: in degree index active_admin i want filter degree based state, because i added hbtm relation between degree and state

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this in degrees.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Degree do
  ...
  filter :states_id, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => proc {State.all}
  ...
end
```